Reason why a customer's email is rejected
I'm having problems with a client's email being rejected.
For some reason, I trigger one of my server's security policies and it rejects it.
The log is as follows:
Aug 23 09:38:57 mail postfix/cleanup[27547]: 33609181759920: message-id=<dc4419d6-274f-45e5-bc40-4e0da311eef9@xxxxx.com>
Aug 23 09:38:57 mail postfix/cleanup[27547]: 33609181759920: reject: header From: Maria <maria@xxxxx.com> from smtpgw.xxxxx.com[x.x.x.x]; from=<maria@xxxxx.com>
to=<secretaria@yyyyy.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<smtpgw.xxxxx.com>: 5.7.1 message content rejected
Aug 23 09:38:57 mail postfix/smtpd[25410]: disconnect from smtpgw.xxxxx.com[x.x.x.x]

How can I find out which policy is being triggered to reject emails from our client?
Is there a place where I can see this and other cases to find the reasons for rejection?

This question is similar to: How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ceejayoz This does not answer my question, as what I am looking for is how to find out which policy is activated to reject our client's email.

@np1 You should just whitelist the recipient, as playing with the default policy can make your organization less safe.

@yagmoth555 That's what I thought.
Even so, for future cases I would like to know if there is a way to know which security policy is activated in these types of cases.
Otherwise it is a matter of going back and forth with the client to find out what they are including in their email for it to be rejected.

Your system is configured to do custom content filtering. The log message 'reject: header From:' tells that this email most likely matches some header_checks rule.
